# How to prevent from submitting page when Validation's for page get failed

Tags: javascript

I wrote date validations code but when date is invalid it is giving alert but not preventing it from submitting.

From form tag i called to method validateDate1 and I also used the keyword return still page is getting submitted when I click on save ch

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return validateDate1(<%=request.getParameter("i_effectiveDates") %>) " action="<%=response.encodeRedirectURL("productDetail.jsp?ec=" + productEntityCode)%>" accept-charset="UTF-8">

function validateDate1(input)
{
    var validformat=/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/ //Basic check for format validity
    var returnval=false
    if (!validformat.test(input.value))
        alert("Invalid Date Format. Please correct and submit again.")
    else
    { //Detailed check for valid date ranges
        var monthfield=input.value.split("/")[0]
        var dayfield=input.value.split("/")[1]
        var yearfield=input.value.split("/")[2]
        var dayobj = new Date(yearfield, monthfield-1, dayfield)
        if ((dayobj.getMonth()+1!=monthfield)||(dayobj.getDate()!=dayfield)||(dayobj.getFullYear()!=yearfield))
            alert("Invalid Day, Month, or Year range detected. Please correct and submit again.")
        else
            returnval=true
    }

    if (returnval==false)       
    input.select()
    return returnval
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `event.preventDefault()` ?

Comment: No. I hav'nt tried event.preventDefault()

Comment: `return false` is OK, no need for preventDefault in simple validation. You need to look in the console for errors

Comment: My guess is you meant to do `onsubmit="return validateDate1(this.<%=request.getParameter("i_effectiveDates") %>)" ` assuming it returns a field name

Comment: i added event.preventDefault() but it is not working Rayon Dabre

Comment: What does `request.getParameter("i_effectiveDates")` return? A field name and does that field exist under that name in the form? Can you post the rendered HTML of the form in your question?

Comment: Actually request.getParameter("i_effectiveDates") will take date from UI and if this date is not valid then it should alert message that invalid format of date . validateDate1 function will take this date and verify